# Find inline images with Asciidoctor API

Tags: ruby, asciidoctor

How can I find all referenced images in an asciidoc file with Asciidoctor API?

I can find block images with `image::file_name[]` however I can't find inline images.

Here is the code I came up with:

```rb
require 'asciidoctor'

input = <<-EOS
= Title

== Chapter 1

image::foo.png[]

=== Section 1.1

image::bar.png[]

This is a paragraph with inline image image:baz.png[].
EOS

doc = Asciidoctor.load input

doc.find_by(context: :image).each do |e|
  pp e.attributes["target"]
end
```

Running this code yields:

```
"foo.png"
"bar.png"
```

But the last inline image`baz.png` is not found.  What / where can I change to find `baz.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Asciidoctor parses inline content during rendering. As a consequence the inline images are not available on the AST (see: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/61)

I believe that this issue will be addressed during the specification process: https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/asciidoc-language